# Read specific columns from CSV file using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I want to plot a graph from .csv file using second and fourth columns.
The data starts from the 9th row, I could skip 8 lines. But I want to access specific columns for plotting graph.

[image: CSV file to be used for plotting graph with col2 and col4]

```
string ChosenFile = "";

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    ChosenFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    char delimited = ',';

    if (new FileInfo(ChosenFile).Length != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = File.ReadLines(@ChosenFile).Skip(8)
               .Select(line => line.Split(new Char[] { delimited }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
               .Select(chunk => chunk
               .Select(x => Double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
               .ToArray());

            series.Points.Clear();
            foreach (var pair in data)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(pair[0], pair[1]);                          
            }
       }
        catch
        {
            logger.info("The file " + openFileDialog1.FileName + " cannot be opened because the content may be invalid or damaged.");
        }
    }
    else logger.info(openFileDialog1.FileName + " is an empty file.");
}
```

This LINQ statement accesses only first two columns, but for my application I need to access data from second and fourth columns
What changes do I need to make in this statement to get these columns?

Comment: Well second and fourth are: `pair[1]` and `pair[3]`..

Comment: It's working with  `pair[1] ` and  `pair[3] `. I was focusing on `.Select(line => line.Split(` in LINQ statement to get these columns. It was a silly thing !                    Thanks @GertArnold and @DragandDrop.

Comment: Yes your issue was namming it pair. somewhere in your mind there were only 2 value in this array :). Now that you have a working solution I will update my answer to show an exemple with an external lib for CSV handeling. So you can have proper Tools next time you have to deal with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's fix your issue. Every column are in your data, you can access them by the index.

```
char delimited = ',';
var inputCSV = @"Skip it
Skip ita
Skip it
Col1,Col2,Foo,Bar
2.3,0.2,3.0,40.5
2.3,0.2,3.0,40.5
2.3,0.2,3.0,40.5";

var fileReadLinesMimic = inputCSV
                    .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var data = fileReadLinesMimic
            .Skip(4)
            .Select(line => line.Split(new Char[] { delimited }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .Select(chunk =>
                chunk.Select(x => Double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            )
            .ToArray());

foreach (var item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Col1={item[0]}; Col2={item[1]}; Foo={item[2]}; Bar={item[3]};");
}
```